# Using jQuery's clearInterval() in a child div

Tags: jquery

I need to stop an interval set up inside a jQuery child div. I found out simply hiding or emptying the div doesn't seem to stop the intervals (opening the div back up seems to keep doubling up on them), so I figured trying it using a function.

Example code;

#### File *Parent.php*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#child').show();
        $('#child').load('child.php');

        // Close it
        jQuery('#close').click(function() {
            $('#child').myfunction(); // <--- attempt
            $('#child').empty();
            $('#child').hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id=child></div>
<div id=close>CLOSE IT</div>
```

#### File *child.php*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.fn.myFunction = function () {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };

        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            $('#child2').load('child2.php');
        }, 5000);

    });
</script>

<div id=child2></div>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You named it `$.fn.myFunction`, but you called it as `.myfunction`.

Comment: How are you opening the DIV back up?

Comment: click.. $('#child').load('child.php') thing

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I copied your code and added a DIV with `$("#start").click(function() $('#child').show(); 
            $('#child').load('child.php');
        });`. When I click in the `start` DIV, it starts the timer again, but it doesn't double up.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using console to debug, and it keeps the interval running (and refreshing) even when the div is hidden and emptied. I really don't understand it at all :(

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. I added `console.log("updating")` to the interval function. When I click the close button, it stops logging. See http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/parent.php

Comment: Did you fix the `myfunction` typo?